# Can I get a 6-month UK tourist visa if I'm unemployed?

Tags: uk, india, standard-visitor-visas

I am from India. My husband is going to the UK to work for 5 months. So I want to go with him as a tourist, but I'm unemployed and don't maintain a proper bank balance to travel. But I can manage all of the travel expenses before leaving, which would be given by my father-in-law from India. I can show his bank balance details. Is this approved in the UK visa application?

Comment: What visa is your husband on?

Comment: Since you are married, it will be understandable that one of the partners won't have a bank account and a job. They will look at the situation and finances of the entire family. There could be a problem if they found that your *husband* was seen as a low risk of overstay as long as his family stays in India, because then both of you coming raises the perceived risk of overstay for both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to demonstrate strong ties to India that are a compelling reason to return but without a job and assets of your own this will likely be very difficult to do. Obtaining funds from your father-in-law to improve the appearance of your financial situation is unlikely to help. There is an excellent answer here [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) that may help you.